# Excel - Random number between 1 and 4 with probablilty but cannot repeat

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a list of numbers (1, 2, 3, 4) and the probability of them being chosen (1: 50%, 2: 25%, 3: 15%, and 4: 10%.

The formula I use to randomly generate the numbers 1-4 based on probability is below:

```
=LOOKUP(RAND(), {0,0.5,0.75,0.9}, {"1","2","3","4"})
```

It works perfectly.  However, Now I need to use the same formula for three more fields but those fields cannot repeat, so essentially it is "choice 1", "choice 2", "choice 3" and "choice 4" with no repeats.

Any idea on how to generate the random with the same probably but not let it kickback a number already chosen?

So is A2 = 4, then B2, C2, and D2 cannot equal 4.
If A2 = 4, and B2 = 1, then C2 and D2 cannot be 4 or 1.  Make sense?

I'm essentially trying to make a random list of preference to mock up an informational forecast.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: It kind of makes sense, but I'm curious, what's the point of having probabilites, since the probability for each number will be 25%?

Comment: The probability (if you assume RAND() is truly random) is based on the lookup of the first vector so it should come out in the wash pretty well.

Comment: Yes, essentially there is a probability that each number will be 25%.  This is where choice #1 and choice #2 come into play.  I believe they will most likely be 1 or 2 but there will be a few 3 and 4's in there so I need to make a list of the first 3 with the random probability and the last one being the remaining number.

Comment: With only 4 numbers it doesn't come out to a wash due to the higher probability of numbers 1 and 2.

Comment: If he is generating unit test type scenarios (which is what I initially thought) then he will get his desired ratios at each point, more or less, once he generates enough datasets. That's how I was looking at his issue.